# why yield is used in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tk-toolkit, yield

*what is use of yield in following code *
*these part of following program. I have some knowledge about generator function and yield, but don't have about how it works in for loop.*

```
for i in range(len(lengthList) - 1):
        for j in range(len(lengthList) - i - 1):
            if(lengthList[j] > lengthList[j + 1]):
                lengthList[j] , lengthList[j + 1] = lengthList[j + 1] , lengthList[j]
                barList[j], barList[j + 1] = barList[j + 1] , barList[j]
                swap(barList[j + 1] , barList[j])
                yield
```

**here is complete code**

*this is for shorting algorithm visualization*

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
```

## Function to swap two bars that will be animated

```
def swap(pos_0, pos_1):
    bar11, _, bar12, _ = canvas.coords(pos_0)
    bar21, _, bar22, _ = canvas.coords(pos_1)
    canvas.move(pos_0, bar21-bar11, 0)
    canvas.move(pos_1, bar12-bar22, 0)

worker = None 

#Insertion Sort
def _insertion_sort():
    global barList
    global lengthList

    for i in range(len(lengthList)):
        cursor = lengthList[i]
        cursorBar = barList[i]
        pos = i

        while pos > 0 and lengthList[pos - 1] > cursor:
            lengthList[pos] = lengthList[pos - 1]
            barList[pos], barList[pos - 1] = barList[pos - 1], barList[pos]
            swap(barList[pos],barList[pos-1])   
            yield                                      
            pos -= 1                                   

        lengthList[pos] = cursor
        barList[pos] = cursorBar
        swap(barList[pos],cursorBar)
```

## Bubble Sort

```
def _bubble_sort():
    global barList
    global lengthList

    for i in range(len(lengthList) - 1):
        for j in range(len(lengthList) - i - 1):
            if(lengthList[j] > lengthList[j + 1]):
                lengthList[j] , lengthList[j + 1] = lengthList[j + 1] , lengthList[j]
                barList[j], barList[j + 1] = barList[j + 1] , barList[j]
                swap(barList[j + 1] , barList[j])
                yield
```

## Selection Sort

```
def _selection_sort():
    global barList    
    global lengthList

    for i in range(len(lengthList)):
        min = i
        for j in range(i + 1 ,len(lengthList)):
            if(lengthList[j] < lengthList[min]):
                min = j
        lengthList[min], lengthList[i] = lengthList[i] ,lengthList[min]
        barList[min] , barList[i] = barList[i] , barList[min]
        swap(barList[min] , barList[i])        
        yield
```

## Triggering Fuctions

```
def insertion_sort():     
    global worker
    worker = _insertion_sort()
    animate()

def selection_sort():     
    global worker
    worker = _selection_sort()
    animate()

def bubble_sort():     
    global worker
    worker = _bubble_sort()
    animate()
```

## Animation Function

```
def animate():      
    global worker
    if worker is not None:
        try:
            next(worker)
            window.after(10, animate)    
        except StopIteration:            
            worker = None
        finally:
            window.after_cancel(animate)
```

## Generator function for generating data

```
def generate():
    global barList
    global lengthList
    canvas.delete('all')
    barstart = 5
    barend = 15
    barList = []
    lengthList = []

    #Creating a rectangle
    for bar in range(1, 60):
        randomY = random.randint(1, 360)
        bar = canvas.create_rectangle(barstart, randomY, barend, 365, fill='yellow')
        barList.append(bar)
        barstart += 10
        barend += 10

    #Getting length of the bar and appending into length list
    for bar in barList:
        bar = canvas.coords(bar)
        length = bar[3] - bar[1]
        lengthList.append(length)

    #Maximum is colored Red
    #Minimum is colored Black
    for i in range(len(lengthList)-1):
        if lengthList[i] == min(lengthList):
            canvas.itemconfig(barList[i], fill='red')
        elif lengthList[i] == max(lengthList):
            canvas.itemconfig(barList[i], fill='black')
```

## Making a window using the Tk widget

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Sorting Visualizer')
window.geometry('600x450')

#Making a Canvas within the window to display contents
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width='600', height='400')
canvas.grid(column=0,row=0, columnspan = 50)

#Buttons
insert = tk.Button(window, text='Insertion Sort', command=insertion_sort)
select = tk.Button(window, text='Selection Sort', command=selection_sort)
bubble = tk.Button(window, text='Bubble Sort', command=bubble_sort)
shuf = tk.Button(window, text='Shuffle', command=generate)
insert.grid(column=1,row=1)
select.grid(column=2,row=1)
bubble.grid(column=3,row=1)
shuf.grid(column=0, row=1)

generate()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: In bubble_function when yield is removed the bubble short animation disappers it only shows finale result.I want know how yield working in this code.

Comment: It's working the way [*yield always works*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Comment: What is your question? Why the massive code dump?

Comment: What is your question? Why the massive code dump? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at all your functions they have global variables, this means that your functions update global variables and do not need to return something, this why you have a simple `yield` when they are called for the next step they are called to update some globals not to return/yield something

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: you have a simple `yield` because your function(s) have to update global variables, in a simple aswer :)

Comment: In  bubble_function when yield is removed the bubble short animation disappers it only shows finale result.I want know how yield working in this code

Comment: you can read more about gloabals [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)

Comment: @VinayakKhandekar it sounds like you are asking what `yield` does to begin with?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga no

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Yield is doing what it always does.